# make the task as success in airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a task in Airflow that uses bash operator which is running continuously.
Is there any way to make the task instance as success before its next scheduled run? I know how to mark it as success in api.
Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call the api automatically to mark the previous dagrun as success, you can use SimpleHttpOperator as the first task of your dag. This operator might call airflow REST API to request to mark the previous dagrun as success.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/operators.html#simplehttpoperator

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have set max_active_runs=2 so while the current job is running the next scheduled run will be triggered and making the previous run to success.